# How to get accestoken for Subscribe With Google when using Sign In With Google?

Tags: node.js, google-signin

I have to switch from 'Google Sign In' to 'Sign In With Google' (SIWG).
I use passport.js with passport-google-oidc. SIWG works, I ask for the scopes openid, profile and email, and I get it.

But SIWG does not give me any access token as it did before Google Sign In. I need this access token to continue with 'Subscribe With Google' (SWG).
Is there any scope that gives it to me?

As I didn't get from SIWG any access token but at least a 'code' I tried to work with this code.
With google-auth-library and the code, I tried to get an access token. With this library, I use the same id, secret and callback url as with SIWG.
But oAuth2Client.getToken(code) only gives me {"error": "invalid_grant", "error_description": "Bad Request"}
Any idea how to make the request go through ok?

`    // 1. Defining strategy

```
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oidc');

const Config_Account_Passport = {        
// "google" will refer to strategy passport-google-oidc SIWG
Google : new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID : '6...MyClientID0c...apps.googleusercontent.com',
    clientSecret : 'a...MyClientSecret...',
    callbackURL: "https://...UrlOfMyServer.../google/auth",
    passReqToCallback : true
}, async function(req, issuer, profile, done) {
    // verified function
    try {
        // get code
        const code = req.query.code;
        // ...
        // get data for login of user. Store data in database if new user.
        const email = profile.emails[0].value;
        const oauth_id = profile.id;
        // Look for user in database. If new store. In Both cases: Having a user object.
        //...

        // AND now to entitlements (part 4 below)
        await checkEntitlements(user, code);
        // following never executed because checkEntitlements fails -> goes to catch

        // Everything is fine
        return done(null, user)
    } catch(e) {
        return done(true, false);   // error and no user
    }

})
}

module.exports = Config_Account_Passport;

// 2. Applying strategy
//...
passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['openid','profile','email','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/subscribewithgoogle.publications.readonly'], accessType: 'offline'});

// 3. Google calls callbackURL -> Successful verified
//...
function(req, res, next) {
    // in callback from google

    passport.authenticate('google', {}, function (err, user) {
        // verified done

        if (err) {
            // done(true, ...) was called
            // user is stays NOT logged id
            return res.redirect('/user/login');
        }
        return res.redirect('/user/loggedin');
    })

}

// 4. Check entitlements

// First get access token from code
const {OAuth2Client} = require('google-auth-library');

function getAccessToken(code) {
return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {
            const oAuth2Client = new OAuth2Client(
            clientID : '6...MyClientID0c...apps.googleusercontent.com',
            clientSecret : 'a...MyClientSecret...',
            callbackURL: "https://...UrlOfMyServer.../google/auth",
        );

        // Generate the url that will be used for the consent dialog.
        await oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
            access_type: 'offline',
            scope: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/subscribewithgoogle.publications.readonly'],
        });

        const {tokens} = await oAuth2Client.getToken(code);
        // following never executed because getToken fails -> goes to catch
        // "error": "invalid_grant"
        
        //...get access token from tokens

        resolve (token);
    } catch (e){
        return reject(e);
    }
})

}

const Payment_SwG = require('./../modules/Payment/SwG');

// Then Get Entitlement with access token
async function checkEntitlements(user, code) {
return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {
        // first get access token by using code
        const accesstoken = await getAccessToken(code);

        // following never executed because getAccessToken fails -> goes to catch
    
        // get entitlements by access token 
        const entitlements = await Payment_SwG.checkEntitlements(accesstoken);
        //...
    
    } catch(e) {
        return reject(e);
    }
})

}`
```

I tried different scopes. I examined all parameters I got back from SIWG, looking out for an access token.
The Scopes you see in the program code are accepted by SIWG. Execution stops after successful SIWG when I try to get an access token.

Comment: Do you have a link to the documentation to this **Sign In With Google' (SIWG)** you say you are trying to use?

Comment: Yes. The explanation from Google and the documentation for using it with passportjs [link](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/overview)  
[link](https://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-google-oidc/)  
Unfortunately, not explained is how to use it together with subscriptions.

Comment: it should return an access token https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/migration-to-gis#example_credentials

Comment: Linda Lawton states, that it should. That gives me hope. Unfortunately passport-google-oidc doesn't. There is no parameter in the called callback function for this.